Nvidia Graphics Card is not Recognised by Ubuntu
I recently installed Ubuntu on my Asus TUF F15 laptop, which has an inbuilt RTX 3050 GPU. While the GPU is detected in the BIOS, it isn’t recognized by the Ubuntu system. When I run nvidia-smi, I get the following error:
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.  

I've already tried installing the NVIDIA drivers and related tools, but the issue persists.

What where the steps you tried for installing the nvidia driver?

I'd suggest to run $ ubuntu-drivers --gpgpu list to see what that might reveal. Then sudo apt purge <package-name> on all nvidia stuff and select one listed by the above and attempt install and use.

What happens when you try to install the Nvidia drivers automatically with sudo ubuntu-drivers install && sudo reboot ?

@karel reboot doesn't need sudo ;-)

Providing your Ubuntu product & release details helps us to know what options exist for you; as drivers are linux kernel modules; and Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choice; that may provide an easy fix if you're using an older kernel stack with a newer video card for example. You've provided few specifics  thus far.
